# How to determine why longlistselector takes too long to render

Tags: performance, windows-phone-8

I have three longlistselector within a pivot control.
Each longlistselector has between 10-20 items.
When I navigate back to the page that displays the pivot + longlistselector, the page takes about 3 seconds to render on a Nokia Lumia with 512 MB.

I took a performance analysis within Visual Studio 2013 and noticed that a frame had about 85% CPU utilization. Digging into the visual tree showed ~70% rendering time for the item presenter of the pivot. This is then split up to 35%, 16%, 20% for each of the LongListSelectors within the pivot control.

When I expand the ItemPresenter, I can see the LongListSelector consuming most of the time. Below, I can see "ContentPresenter" and Canvas which also take the time.

I took a Memory analysis for the same but the tool could not find anything suspicious there.

How can I check what exactly takes so long to re-render a page which was previously displayed?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it appears to simply be that the LongListSelector has to re-render the contents of your view model when it returns. The only way I could find to improve the situation was to un-hook the ItemSource property of the LLS in the page "OnNavigatedTo" method, and then re-hook it back up programatically in the page "OnLoaded" event (see below for an example)

Unhook:

```
MyLongListSelectorControl.ItemsSource = null;
```

Recreate:

```
Binding ItemSourceBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
MyLongListSelectorControl.SetBinding(LongListSelector.ItemsSourceProperty, ItemSourceBinding);
```

Note that the "MyDataProperty" can be exactly the text you used to bind in XAML.

This way the page at least can visually render completely with some kind of "loading" indicator and then the longlist selector will be populated afterwards, giving the illusion of the app responding perfectly.

Comment: Have had this problem too multiple times... Thanks for the info!!